# How do I get swiping functionality similar to modern banking apps in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Here's an example of the functionality I'm looking for from the Monzo banking app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtHEk.jpg

Essentially I'm just looking for those distinct animations of the card swiping across on the top and the contents below smoothly fading in and out in reaction to the swiping.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

check this out, I am using it currently as well.

https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel

[image]

Comment: Hey, is there any way that I could tie in the fade in and out of the bottom content to the swiping in the carousel? cheers

Comment: well in this situation you can connect the index of the active card above with the match item of  a horizontal Flatlist bellow, and use [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated)
to apply the fade animation etc.
Happy coding ;)